# Why 'apt-get install openssl' did not install last version of OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl, ubuntu-16.04

When I use 'apt-get install openssl', my Ubuntu 16.04 install OpenSSL 1.0.2g version. I expect to install 1.1.0 versions.

Why is not install 1.1.0 version? How can i install the last version?

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: *"How can i install the last version?"* - See [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki. You may be able to find a [Ubuntu PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas), too.

Comment: It is related to programming and development ecosystem, so it's not off-topic.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should choose the version you want to install on the [OpenSSL's](https://www.openssl.org/source/) site. It seems you want to install the 1.1.0.
So, do as it follows.

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.0f.tar.gz
tar xzvf openssl-1.1.0f.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.1.0f
./config -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-rpath,'$(LIBRPATH)'
make
sudo make install

openssl version -a
```

It is done. It is as simple as that.
Good luck with it.

Comment: Do I have to remove previous version?

Comment: It depends on your purpose and environment. If you are just installing an OpenSSL different version on your PC, just install the new version. If it is something more than that, tell me more about what exactly you are doing.

Comment: @edson.a.soares can u please help me with my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48776525/unable-to-install-openssl-1-1-on-ubuntu-8?

Comment: There's no need to use `sudo` for the `make` command. You might need it for `make install` if you're installing in a location that requires root permissions.

Comment: Hi, @RanPaul. I see Keith has answered your question. I think there nothing more to say about it. About the `sudo` issue when you are running make, that is correct, most of the time. Thank you, Keith. I will correct the answer. A practical example of it would be [that way](https://www.eriksmistad.no/getting-started-with-google-test-on-ubuntu) to install **Google Test framework**. Once you're in a location that requires root permissions, you'll need `sudo`.

Comment: Hi @edson.a.soares can you help me with my issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51560964/how-to-upgrade-openssl-from-1-0-2g-to-1-1-0g-in-ubuntu-and-let-python-recognize). I followed the instruction here. The old OpenSSL is still the one that appears when I check the version via: `openssl version -a`. I do not get `openssl 1.1.0g`. I need to use `openssl 1.1.0g` with python 3.6.5. Please help.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/openssl version` printed the right version.

Comment: Holy cow this is reckless advice.  Don't just download the raw upstream version of packaged software used all over your system and `make install` it.  Things. Will. Break.  In this case, you'll end up with two versions of openssl - the distro one managed by apt under /usr and a second one installed in /usr/local.  When updating to the newer Ubuntu, apt will update its version, and this manual one will be left.  Locally-built programs might be linked against one or the other, depending on environment variables.  It'll make a mess long-term, and possibly short-term.

Comment: Nope! It's not reckless advice. It's a simple way to install Open SSL meant for simple cases. Of course, it won't fit all scenarios. No solution does. There is a lot of possibilities taking into account the scenario. That's why I asked for more information if it was for more than installing OpenSSL on a Personal Computer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu 18+, version 1.1.0 is now be available via `apt`.

You can also use `apt list openssl` to see what can be updated. And even throw in the `-a` modifier to show all versions available.

Comment: Nope. The 1.1.x aren't available via apt (today: October 2019). Have: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS. Successfully run "apt update". Now output of "apt list openssl -a" shows only 1.0.2. Quote:    Listing... Done
openssl/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.15 amd64 [installed]
openssl/xenial 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4 amd64

Comment: Yes. Sorry, it looks like 1.1.1 is only available in Ubuntu 18.0+ LTS. I'll add that to my answer. Thank you!