# Unable to Install OpenSSL 1.1 on Ubuntu 8

Tags: ubuntu, openssl

I was following the article [Why 'apt-get install openssl' did not install last version of OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887754/why-apt-get-install-openssl-did-not-install-last-version-of-openssl) to install openssl on my UBuntu box but am getting command not found on my ubuntu box, am a windows user and this is my first time experience on ubuntu box and not sure how it fix it

Below is my Ubuntu Version

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 8.04.1
Release:        8.04
Codename:       hardy
```

I have manually downloaded OpenSSL 1.1 from https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.0f.tar.gz and uploaded to ubuntu server via FTP and run the below commands

`sudo ./config -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-rpath,'$(LIBRPATH)'`

```
output: sudo: ./config: command not found
```

`sudo make`

```
output: sudo: make: command not found
```

`sudo make install`

```
output: sudo: make: command not found
```

I'm not sure hot fix this `command not found`, can someone please me to fix it and isntall OpenSSL?

Comment: Ubuntu 8.04 is nearly 10 years old and is no longer supported. Why are you running such an old version?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: There are a lot of modern programs and libraries that do not build against OpenSSL 1.1.x, like OpenSSL 1.1.0. Going back in time to Ubuntu 8 is going to be more painful. Maybe you should consider OpenSSL 1.0.x, like OpenSSL 1.0.2. That will give you a fighting chance.

Comment: Also see [Noloader | Build-Scripts](https://github.com/noloader/Build-Scripts). I use it to update Git, SSH, Wget, OpenSSL and several other programs on ancient clients, like Fedora 7 and Ubuntu 10. Git and SSH require OpenSSL 1.0.2 because they have not been ported to OpenSSL 1.1.0 yet. (I use the ancient clients because they come with the compiler I need to test, like GCC 4.0 and GCC 4.3).

Comment: And stop using `sudo` for everything. Do everything as an unprivileged user. Use `sudo` for the install only. That is, the only `sudo` command should be `sudo make install`. This is Linux 101. Also see [when should I use sudo](https://www.google.com/search?q=when+should+I+use+sudo).

Comment: @jww we are going get rid of  our legacy systems completely by the end of the year,till then we need to support it and enforce stronger SSL security protocol like `TLS1.2`, presently we are running on `apache 2.2` which doesnt have OpenSSL to provide `TLS1.2`, so we are setting OpenSSL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a newer version available currently 1.1.0g.  You should check https://www.openssl.org/source/ to see what's available.

You should read the `INSTALL` file before doing anything else.

You shouldn't be seeing `./config: command not found` if you're in the right directory. Did you run the `cd` command? Is it possible that the `config` script lost its execution permission? What does `ls -l config` say?

`make: command not found` indicates that you haven't installed the `make` command. The easiest way to install it, along with other development tools, is:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

There's no need to use `sudo` for the `config` or `make` command. You can use it for `make install` if you're installing in a location that requires root access.

Comment: It was an issue with permissions so I ran `sudo chmod -R 777 openssl` and tried running `./config` command now its giving me `Perl v5.10.0 required--this is only v5.8.8`, am having issues with setting up Perl v5.10, can u pleae help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48795195/upgrade-perl-v5-8-to-perl-v5-10-on-on-ubuntu-8

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 777` is massive overkill -- and if you did that on the installation directory (containing the executables and libraries) it opens a gaping security hole. 777 gives all users permission to modify everything in the directory tree. As for having an old version of Perl, I think you're wasting your time trying to install modern packages on an ancient OS.

Comment: is there any other command that I can run instead of `sudo chmod -R 777` to giver permission for the executable?

Comment: @RanPaul: `chmod +x`. But if you've really run `chmod -R 777` to change the permissions of everything in the installation directory, the best way to recover from that is to remove the installation directory and start over. If you did the installation correctly in the first place, you won't need to use `chmod` yourself. If you didn't do the installation correctly, don't try to fix the permissions after the fact; just nuke it and try again.