# Upgrade Perl v5.8 to Perl v5.10 on on Ubuntu 8

Tags: perl, ubuntu

I have installed the `Perl v5.10` in `/home/admin/localperl` location as per the below install commands

```
./Configure -des -Dprefix=$HOME/localperl
make test
make install
```

But when I ran the `$ perl -v` command am still seeing `perl, v5.8.8` instead of `Perl v5.10`

```
This is perl, v5.8.8 built for i486-linux-gnu-thread-multi
```

I am a windows user and in the windows world I usually change the class path to make it work, but am not sure how this can be done in `Ubuntu 8` world, can someone please help?

Comment: Run `which perl`. Your shell is still pointing to the system Perl. You need to change your PATH.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why limit your upgrade to such an ancient version? 5.10 is over 10 years old!

Comment: And Ubuntu 8.04 (or 8.08) are equally old -- the leading 8 stands for 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `/bin` appears before `/home/admin/localperl/bin` in your path.

Add the following to your login script:

```
export PATH="/home/admin/localperl/bin:$PATH"
```

(Bourne shell syntax provided; adjust as needed.)

---

Remember, the scripts that should use this Perl should have the following shebang line:

```
#!/home/admin/localperl/bin/perl
```

The standard Perl installers will automatically convert `#!/bin/perl` into the above in scripts they install.